# wsimport fails when trying to create client service library

Tags: java, web-services, soap, mantis

I am trying to create a client library to access [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org) from java. The problem is that I am getting an error and I don't know why.

Running this command:

```
wsimport http://www.mantisbt.org/demo/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl
```

simply fails. It is supposed to create some kind of client libraries for access to the service from java, but I get this error:

```
[ERROR] "Use of SOAP Encoding is not supported. 
SOAP extension element on line 1,075 in http://www.mantisbt.org/demo/api
/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl has use="encoded" "
```

I looked on internet and there are vague references to this error, that it seems as an error of an  directive, but it is not the case: I've tried to fix this problem with a downloaded version of the xml and it didn't work.

I think I could need some kind of catalogue for achieve this generation succesfully, could it be?? If so, does anyone how to create this?? I made some search but my knowledge of web services in general is too limited to achieve that.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is using Axis 1.4 an option? If it is, we have deployed [Axis 1 SOAP stubs for MantisBT](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|biz.futureware.mantis|mantis-axis-soap-client|1.2.9|jar) on Maven central.

Alternatively there is a source project on Github at [jerr/mantis-ws-client](https://github.com/jerr/mantis-ws-client/blob/master/providers/soap-jaxws/) which should how to build artifacts with JAX-RPC.

Comment: Thanks. This API of mantis is disappointing me. And there aren't any "elegant" way of connect java and mantis apart from this.

Comment: Not that I know of. Putting on my Mantis contributor hat, feel free to submit a patch :-) https://github.com/mantisbt/mantisbt

Comment: @RobertMunteanu `mantis-ws-client` not any document for use. can ypu help me to use it?

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the issue is that the mantis WSDL is describing an rpc/encoded web service and that style is not supported in the modern wsimport tool.

A good writeup of the different types of web service styles is at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/.

A related question and self-service answer is provided at [Best way to consume RPC/encoded webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284126/best-way-to-consume-rpc-encoded-webservice).  That answer makes the comment 'I'm also in doubt about using JAX-RPC for this job, because it's way out-dated.', but that really is what you are dealing with here so using the 'old library' really would be the correct way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will have a look to the article you provided. I think I need a concrete answer, despite of your clear explanation of the issue behind, I have to confess that my vote goes for Rober Munteanu.